# Sobel filter in x direction in CUDA

Tags: cuda, textures

I am trying to apply a sobel filter on a grayscale image in the x direction on each pixel and displaying the result.
X direction sobel filter is:-

```
-1 0 1   
-2 0 2  
-1 0 1
```

I am not getting the required results. Can someone point out my mistakes? I am trying to use textures and I am not so sure as to whether I have used it correctly:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define CudaSafeCall( err ) __cudaSafeCall( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#define CudaCheckError()    __cudaCheckError( __FILE__, __LINE__ )
texture <float,2,cudaReadModeElementType> tex1;
//Kernel for x direction sobel
__global__ void implement_x_sobel(float* garbage,float* output,int width,int height,int              widthStep)
{
int x=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
int y=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;

float output_value=((0*tex2D(tex1,x,y))+(2*tex2D(tex1,x+1,y))+(-2*tex2D(tex1,x-  1,y))+(0*tex2D(tex1,x,y+1))+(1*tex2D(tex1,x+1,y+1))+(-1*tex2D(tex1,x-1,y+1))+  (1*tex2D(tex1,x+1,y-1))+(0*tex2D(tex1,x,y-1))+(-1*tex2D(tex1,x-1,y-1)));
output[y*widthStep+x]=output_value;
}
//Kernel for y direction sobel
//__global__ void implement_y_sobel(float* input,float* output,int width,int height,int widthStep)
//{

//}
//Host Code
 inline void __cudaSafeCall( cudaError err, const char *file, const int line )
{
#ifdef CUDA_ERROR_CHECK
if ( cudaSuccess != err )
{
    printf("cudaSafeCall() failed at %s:%i : %s\n",
             file, line, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
    exit( -1 );
}    
#endif

return;
}

inline void __cudaCheckError( const char *file, const int line )
{
#ifdef CUDA_ERROR_CHECK
cudaError err = cudaGetLastError();
if ( cudaSuccess != err )
{
    printf("cudaCheckError() failed at %s:%i : %s\n",
             file, line, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
   exit( -1 );
}
#endif

return;
}



void sobel(float* input,float* output,int width,int height,int widthStep)
{
cudaChannelFormatDesc     channelDesc=cudaCreateChannelDesc(32,32,0,0,cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
cudaArray * cuArray;
CudaSafeCall(cudaMallocArray(&cuArray,&channelDesc,width,height));
cudaMemcpyToArray(cuArray,0,0,input,widthStep*height,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
tex1.addressMode[0]=cudaAddressModeClamp;
tex1.addressMode[1]=cudaAddressModeClamp;
tex1.filterMode=cudaFilterModeLinear;
tex1.normalized=false;
cudaBindTextureToArray(tex1,cuArray,channelDesc);
float * D_output_x;
float * garbage=NULL;
CudaSafeCall(cudaMalloc(&D_output_x,widthStep*height)); 
dim3 blocksize(16,16);
dim3 gridsize;
gridsize.x=(width+blocksize.x-1)/blocksize.x;
gridsize.y=(height+blocksize.y-1)/blocksize.y;

//kernel call
implement_x_sobel<<<gridsize,blocksize>>>(garbage,D_output_x,width,height,widthStep/sizeof(float));
cudaThreadSynchronize();
CudaCheckError();
CudaSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(output,D_output_x,height*widthStep,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
cudaFree(D_output_x);
cudaFree(garbage);
cudaFreeArray(cuArray);
}
```

My main file:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<opencv/highgui.h>
#include<opencv/cv.h>
#include"header.h"
using namespace std;
void main()
{
IplImage* img1=cvLoadImage("C://test.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); 
if( !img1) {
           printf("ERROR: couldnt load file!\n");
           }
IplImage* img2=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),IPL_DEPTH_32F,img1->nChannels);
IplImage* img3=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),IPL_DEPTH_32F,img1->nChannels);
unsigned char * pseudo_input=(unsigned char *)img1->imageData;
float * output=(float*)img2->imageData;
float *input=(float*)img3->imageData;
int s=img1->widthStep/sizeof(float);
for(int w=0;w<=(img1->height);w++)
    for(int h=0;h<(img1->width*img1->nChannels);h++)
    {
        input[w*s+h]= pseudo_input[w*s+h];
            }

sobel(input,output,img1->width,img1->height,img1->widthStep);
cvShowImage("Original Image",img1);
cvShowImage("Sobeled Image",img2);
cvWaitKey(0);
    }}
```

Comment: Your code does no error checking. I recommend adding error checking code and fixing any errors and then if your question still remains, update your code.

Comment: @harrism-included error checking as you suggested,still having the same problem.

Comment: There are templated versions of cudaCreateChannelDesc() that you can use to key off the type instead of trying to puzzle out the parameters:
cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();

Comment: And do you get any errors?  What results do you get?

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware... availability of template functions depends on which version of CUDA Toolkit is being used.

Comment: @harrism both my .cu and main files compile correctly with no errors.
But on running the program, I just get nothing.

Comment: Nothing as in no output?  Did you try a debugger?

Comment: Basically I am using an emulator (compute capabilty 1.3 in theory) with visual studio 2008 or a CPU debugger.

Answer (score 1):

`cudaCreateChannelDesc` expects as first 4 parameters the number of bits for x, y, z, and w components. It should be 32 for `float` texture.

```
cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 32, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to diagnose the problem without more information.  If you are getting no meaningful output (e.g. texture is reading all 0's), that implies a problem with your texture setup or binding.

If you are off by a little bit, that is probably because you need to offset the coordinates by 0.5f, and while you are at it, be more careful about explicitly converting your ints to floats.  The code won't run any slower if you declare and assign float-valued variables before calling tex2D().