# Applying Sobel Edge Detection with CUDA and OpenCV on a grayscale jpg image

Tags: image, opencv, cuda

This question has already been asked before, but the asker didn't provide enough information and left unanswered and I am curious about the program.

[**Original Question Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091274/sobel-filter-in-x-direction-in-cuda)

I'm trying to do a sobel edge detection using both opencv and cuda library, 
the sobel kernel for X direction is

```
-1 0 1   
-2 0 2  
-1 0 1
```

I have 3 files in my project

```
main.cpp
CudaKernel.cu
CudaKernel.h
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\gpu\gpu.hpp>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>
#include "CudaKernel.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    IplImage* image;

    try
    {
        image = cvLoadImage("4555472_460s.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        gpu::DeviceInfo info = gpu::getDevice();
        cout << info.name() << endl;
        cout << "Stream Processor : "<< info.multiProcessorCount() << endl;
        cout << "Total Graphic Memory :" << info.totalMemory()/1048576 << " MB" << endl; 
    }
    catch (const cv::Exception* ex)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << ex->what() << endl;
    }
    if(!image )
        {
             cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
             return -1;
        }


    IplImage* image2=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),IPL_DEPTH_32F,image->nChannels);
    IplImage* image3=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),IPL_DEPTH_32F,image->nChannels);

    unsigned char * pseudo_input=(unsigned char *)image->imageData;
    float *output=(float*)image2->imageData;
    float *input=(float*)image3->imageData;
    int s=image->widthStep/sizeof(float);
        for(int w=0;w<=(image->height);w++)
            for(int h=0;h<(image->width*image->nChannels);h++)
            {
                input[w*s+h]= pseudo_input[w*s+h];
            }


    Pixel *fagget  = (unsigned char*) image->imageData;
    kernelcall(input, output, image->width,image->height, image->widthStep);

//  cv::namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    cvShowImage( "Original Image", image ); // Show our image inside it.
    cvShowImage("Sobeled Image", image2);
    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;

}
```

**CudaKernel.cu**

```
#include<cuda.h>
#include<iostream>
#include "CudaKernel.h"
using namespace std;
#define CudaSafeCall( err ) __cudaSafeCall( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#define CudaCheckError()    __cudaCheckError( __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#define checkCudaErrors(err) __checkCudaErrors (err, __FILE__, __LINE__)


texture <float,2,cudaReadModeElementType> tex1;
texture<unsigned char, 2> tex;
static cudaArray *array = NULL;
static cudaArray *cuArray = NULL;


//Kernel for x direction sobel
__global__ void implement_x_sobel(float* garbage,float* output,int width,int height,int widthStep)
{
    int x=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int y=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;

    float output_value=((0*tex2D(tex1,x,y))+(2*tex2D(tex1,x+1,y))+(-2*tex2D(tex1,x-  1,y))+(0*tex2D(tex1,x,y+1))+(1*tex2D(tex1,x+1,y+1))+(-1*tex2D(tex1,x-1,y+1))+  (1*tex2D(tex1,x+1,y-1))+(0*tex2D(tex1,x,y-1))+(-1*tex2D(tex1,x-1,y-1)));
    output[y*widthStep+x]=output_value;
}


inline void __checkCudaErrors( cudaError err, const char *file, const int line )
{
    if( cudaSuccess != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s(%i) : CUDA Runtime API error %d: %s.\n",
                file, line, (int)err, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
        exit(-1);
    }
}   

//Host Code
 inline void __cudaSafeCall( cudaError err, const char *file, const int line )
{
#ifdef CUDA_ERROR_CHECK
if ( cudaSuccess != err )
{
    printf("cudaSafeCall() failed at %s:%i : %s\n",
             file, line, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
    exit( -1 );
}    
#endif

return;
}
inline void __cudaCheckError( const char *file, const int line )
{
#ifdef CUDA_ERROR_CHECK
cudaError err = cudaGetLastError();
if ( cudaSuccess != err )
{
    printf("cudaCheckError() failed at %s:%i : %s\n",
             file, line, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
   exit( -1 );
}
#endif

return;
}

void kernelcall(float* input,float* output,int width,int height,int widthStep){
    //cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc=cudaCreateChannelDesc(32,32,0,0,cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
    //cudaArray *cuArray;
    CudaSafeCall(cudaMallocArray(&cuArray,&channelDesc,width,height));
    cudaMemcpyToArray(cuArray,0,0,input,widthStep*height,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    tex1.addressMode[0]=cudaAddressModeClamp;
    tex1.addressMode[1]=cudaAddressModeClamp;
    tex1.filterMode=cudaFilterModeLinear;
    cudaBindTextureToArray(tex1,cuArray,channelDesc);
    tex1.normalized=false;
    float * D_output_x;
    float * garbage=NULL;
    CudaSafeCall(cudaMalloc(&D_output_x,widthStep*height)); 
    dim3 blocksize(16,16);
    dim3 gridsize;
    gridsize.x=(width+blocksize.x-1)/blocksize.x;
    gridsize.y=(height+blocksize.y-1)/blocksize.y;

    implement_x_sobel<<<gridsize,blocksize>>>(garbage,D_output_x,width,height,widthStep/sizeof(float));
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    CudaCheckError();
    CudaSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(output,D_output_x,height*widthStep,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    cudaFree(D_output_x);
    cudaFree(garbage);
    cudaFreeArray(cuArray);
}
```

the result is really messed up, it didnt look like the original image at all

**Result:**

[image: Incorrect Result]

I changed some line of the code to

```
float *pseudo_input=(float *)image->imageData;
float *output=(float*)image2->imageData;
float *input=(float*)image3->imageData;
float *inputnormalized=(float *)image4->imageData;

int s=image->widthStep/sizeof(float);
for(int w=0;w<=(image->height);w++)
    for(int h=0;h<(image->width*image->nChannels);h++)
    {
        input[w*s+h]= pseudo_input[w*s+h];
    }


kernelcall(input, output, image->width,image->height, image->widthStep);

cvNormalize(input,inputnormalized,0,255,NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);

cvShowImage( "Original Image", image ); // Show our image inside it.
cvShowImage("Sobeled Image", image2);
```

But now I get an unhandled exception error.

Comment: Generally it is suggested that you start a bounty on a question rather than ask a possible duplicate.

Comment: If you just searching for an gpu sobel filter, gpu opencv provides already several filter function and it seems they have a [sobel filter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/image_filtering.html#gpu-createderivfilter-gpu), too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV rule number 1:

> Never access the image data directly through the underlying data pointer unless
>   absolutely necessary, e.g copying data to GPU. Reference (Me :p)

**Errors/Recommendations:**

1. Instead of converting the image by looping through the image data
   pointer, use `cvConvert` to change image data type. Looping is very
   much prone to error.
2. When calling the function named `kernelcall`, you are passing the
   data pointer of `float` images, but passing the `widthStep` of the
   original 8 bit image. This is the main cause of erronous results as
   it will result in incorrect indexing inside the kernel.
3. When performing memory copy between 2 pitched pointers which have
   different widthSteps, ALWAYS use 2D memory copy functions available
   in CUDA Runtime, e.g. `cudaMemcpy2D`, `cudaMemcpy2DToArray` etc. In your case, the `cuArray` has unknown widthstep internally, and the input `IplImage` has different widthStep than that of `cuArray` .
4. Avoid unnecessary headers, assignments and identifier declaration.
5. Add bound checks inside the CUDA kernel, so that only those threads perform memory read/write which fall inside the image. It may cause a little divergence, but its better than invalid memory read/writes.

## Revised Code (Tested):

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "CudaKernel.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    IplImage* image;

    image = cvLoadImage("4555472_460s.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    if(!image )
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


    IplImage* image2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),IPL_DEPTH_32F,image->nChannels);
    IplImage* image3 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),IPL_DEPTH_32F,image->nChannels);

    //Convert the input image to float
    cvConvert(image,image3);

    float *output = (float*)image2->imageData;
    float *input =  (float*)image3->imageData;

    kernelcall(input, output, image->width,image->height, image3->widthStep);

    //Normalize the output values from 0.0 to 1.0
    cvScale(image2,image2,1.0/255.0);

    cvShowImage("Original Image", image );
    cvShowImage("Sobeled Image", image2);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

**CudaKernel.cu**

```
#include<cuda.h>
#include<iostream>
#include "CudaKernel.h"

using namespace std;

#define CudaSafeCall( err ) __cudaSafeCall( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#define CudaCheckError()    __cudaCheckError( __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#define checkCudaErrors(err) __checkCudaErrors (err, __FILE__, __LINE__)


texture <float,2,cudaReadModeElementType> tex1;

static cudaArray *cuArray = NULL;

//Kernel for x direction sobel
__global__ void implement_x_sobel(float* output,int width,int height,int widthStep)
{
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    //Make sure that thread is inside image bounds
    if(x<width && y<height)
    {
        float output_value = (-1*tex2D(tex1,x-1,y-1)) + (0*tex2D(tex1,x,y-1)) + (1*tex2D(tex1,x+1,y-1))
                           + (-2*tex2D(tex1,x-1,y))   + (0*tex2D(tex1,x,y))   + (2*tex2D(tex1,x+1,y))
                           + (-1*tex2D(tex1,x-1,y+1)) + (0*tex2D(tex1,x,y+1)) + (1*tex2D(tex1,x+1,y+1));

        output[y*widthStep+x]=output_value;
    }

}


inline void __checkCudaErrors( cudaError err, const char *file, const int line )
{
    if( cudaSuccess != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s(%i) : CUDA Runtime API error %d: %s.\n",
            file, line, (int)err, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
        exit(-1);
    }
}   

//Host Code
inline void __cudaSafeCall( cudaError err, const char *file, const int line )
{
#ifdef CUDA_ERROR_CHECK
    if ( cudaSuccess != err )
    {
        printf("cudaSafeCall() failed at %s:%i : %s\n",
            file, line, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
        exit( -1 );
    }    
#endif

    return;
}
inline void __cudaCheckError( const char *file, const int line )
{
#ifdef CUDA_ERROR_CHECK
    cudaError err = cudaGetLastError();
    if ( cudaSuccess != err )
    {
        printf("cudaCheckError() failed at %s:%i : %s\n",
            file, line, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
        exit( -1 );
    }
#endif

    return;
}

void kernelcall(float* input,float* output,int width,int height,int widthStep)
{
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();

    CudaSafeCall(cudaMallocArray(&cuArray,&channelDesc,width,height));

    //Never use 1D memory copy if host and device pointers have different widthStep.
    // You don't know the width step of CUDA array, so its better to use cudaMemcpy2D...
    cudaMemcpy2DToArray(cuArray,0,0,input,widthStep,width * sizeof(float),height,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaBindTextureToArray(tex1,cuArray,channelDesc);

    float * D_output_x;
    CudaSafeCall(cudaMalloc(&D_output_x,widthStep*height)); 

    dim3 blocksize(16,16);
    dim3 gridsize;
    gridsize.x=(width+blocksize.x-1)/blocksize.x;
    gridsize.y=(height+blocksize.y-1)/blocksize.y;

    implement_x_sobel<<<gridsize,blocksize>>>(D_output_x,width,height,widthStep/sizeof(float));

    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    CudaCheckError();

    //Don't forget to unbind the texture
    cudaUnbindTexture(tex1);

    CudaSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(output,D_output_x,height*widthStep,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    cudaFree(D_output_x);
    cudaFreeArray(cuArray);
}
```

Comment: your code is worked perfectly and simpler, thanks for pointing my errors too! I really appreciated it

Comment: Your code is very helpful. But I have a question: why use float array to store the input and output? can I use unsigned char array?

Comment: I used float because the OP intended to use it. Yes you can use `unsigned char`. You would have to create host images `image2` and `image3` of depth `IPL_DEPTH_8U` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here:-

unsigned char * pseudo_input=(unsigned char *)image->imageData;
float *output=(float*)image2->imageData;
float *input=(float*)image3->imageData;
int s=image->widthStep/sizeof(float);
    for(int w=0;w<=(image->height);w++)
        for(int h=0;h<(image->width*image->nChannels);h++)
        {
            input[w*s+h]= pseudo_input[w*s+h];
        }
```

input is float* and pseudo_input is uchar* . convert everything to float and then process. In the end normalize between 0 ans 255 using cvNormalize with NORM_MINMAX to get proper results.

Comment: ok i changed the code, but now i get an unhandled exception error

Comment: normalize after processing. use cvNormalize(input,inputnormalized,0,255,NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1)

Comment: so normalize it after the Cuda kernel call ?

Comment: the cvNormalize function always resulted in unhandled exception error, check my post, i updated the code

Comment: you cannot use normalize for float*. It must be Mat

Comment: please give me more clue about how to do the normalization

Comment: @user1979092... Normalization is done by dividing each pixel by the maximum possible value of the image data-type. You can use `cvScale` to normalize the image.